# how do I hide/display the submit button in React JS

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am completely new to React JS, I have no Idea how to do in ReactJS.

I have to hide the Submit button initially, when  keyin to  dates fields then Submit button should be display.

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { startdate: '', enddate: '' };
    }
    mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("You are submitting " + this.state.startdate +"and"+ this.state.enddate);
    }
    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
      this.setState({startdate: event.target.value});
    }

    myEndDate = (event) => {
        this.setState({enddate: event.target.value});
      }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
        <img src="C:\\Users\\A9002255\\Desktop\is.jpg"></img>
        <h2>Please select the Date range of .CSV </h2>
       
        <input
          type='date'
          onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />
        <span>   </span>
       <input
          type="date"
          onChange={this.myEndDate}
        />
        <div>
        <input
          type='submit' value="Download" class="bi bi-cloud-arrow-down"  style={{ width: '10%', height: 30}}
        />
        </div>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

  export default MyForm;
```

Comment: How is this related to java?

Comment: You can use ternary operator for these kind of things. `{this.state.enddate ? (<input type='submit' value="Download" class="bi bi-cloud-arrow-down"  style={{ width: '10%', height: 30}} />) : null}`

Comment: What is keyin meant?

Comment: how to validate the dates range for particular period? example: user can select dates within the 3 years based on start date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add check on base of start and end dates of your state.
Try following code

```
   class MyForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { startdate: '', enddate: '' };
}
mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("You are submitting " + this.state.startdate +"and"+ this.state.enddate);
}
myChangeHandler = (event) => {
  this.setState({startdate: event.target.value});
}

myEndDate = (event) => {
    this.setState({enddate: event.target.value});
  }

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
    <img src="C:\\Users\\A9002255\\Desktop\is.jpg"></img>
    <h2>Please select the Date range of .CSV </h2>
   
    <input
      type='date'
      onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
    />
    <span>   </span>
   <input
      type="date"
      onChange={this.myEndDate}
    />
    <div>
    {this.state.startdate && this.state.enddate && <input
      type='submit' value="Download" class="bi bi-cloud-arrow-down"  style={{ width: '10%', height: 30}}
    />}
    </div>
    </form>
  );
}


}
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default MyForm;
```